# Drupal 7: how to build a form system

Tags: 7, nodes, forms, entities

- I want to build something like:
- We have 2 type of users: staff and student.
- Student logins into a drupal site, then a collection of forms presented to the student
- Form type 1: Student selects a form then fill in all fields. After hitting the submit button, data will be saved as a node.
- Form type 2: Similar as form type 1, except the same student visits the same form, s/he will see the previous data s/he entered.
- Very similar situation for staff.
- I wonder what are the basic steps I need to take.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't give the complete solution, Yet I will try to relate things what you have asked to things what we have in Drupal,

1. Form type 1 =>  Any Node type (say Article)
2. Form type 2 =>  Any Node type (say blog)
3. Student => Drupal User (has a profile of student, use [profiles2](http://drupal.org/project/profile2) module )
4. Teacher => Drupal User (has a profile of Teacher, use [profiles2](http://drupal.org/project/profile2) module )

User [Permissions](http://drupal.org/node/1096972) for Node creation, Node edit by its own author. [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) to display the forms and user [redirection](http://drupal.org/project/login_destination) module to get something you want.